# Hide an option on dropdown menu using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select class="bookly-select-mobile bookly-js-select-employee">
    <option value="">Any</option>
    <option value="1">Brandon Davis</option>
    <option value="2">Ryan Floyd</option>
</select>
```

is there a javascript that can hide the "Any" option?

Comment: CSS: option[value=""] {display: none}

Comment: @c69 - Like this - .bookly-js-select-employee .bookly-select-mobile
option[value=""] {display: none;}

Comment: If you did NOT meant to put the space between classes - then yes.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is set `display: none` in CSS. One way to do this (assuming anything with a blank value should be hidden) is to use `option[value='']` as your selector.

Of course, if you want to do this dynamically (in JS), you'll have to have some way to target the element.

Comment: Like this - .bookly-js-select-employee .bookly-select-mobile
option[value=""] {display: none;}

Comment: If that's how you target the element, then yes!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do it with `hidden` attribute. Documentation here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp

```html
<select class="bookly-select-mobile bookly-js-select-employee">
    <option hidden value="">Any</option>
    <option value="1">Brandon Davis</option>
    <option value="2">Ryan Floyd</option>    
</select>
```